# How optimize mesh (minimize tris and vertics)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

had a big model with 3,1M tris and 4,9M vertics. I want optimze mesh, short count tris and vertics. How do it?

Comment: Is there a programming related issue we can help you with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: This probably isn't on-topic for this site, unless you're trying to code a mesh optimization algorithm. This also isn't a Unity-specific problem, so try checking the Blender or Maya documentation/help forums (depending on what 3D modelling software is available to you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import your model to blender and use  decimator modifier to reduce vertex count  then reimport it to unity.

[blender docs decimator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html)

Answer (score 1):

[MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) is a great tool for this.