# LOD models for Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I have big model of buildings. It contains 3M triagles. I make viewer of this model. In runtime then camera show all model - fps very low. I want user LOD Unity3d. What tools exists for LOD? (What you prefer?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How optimize mesh (minimize tris and vertics)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775773/how-optimize-mesh-minimize-tris-and-vertics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard good things about [this asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12079) if you want to simplify the mesh within the Unity Editor rather than in your modeling app.

Comment: My model consist of about 28500 gameobjects. With this asset I need each process - very long. I want build low poly model automatic.

Comment: Ah, got it. You could use something like MeshBaker (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/31895) to combine multiple models into a single mesh (and atlas textures for draw call performance), then decimate the resulting mesh. This process could likely be scripted pretty easily. Good luck!